# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'value')

I need to get the values from the login form (inputs: username and password) but when I submit the form the error appears.

AuthContext.js

```js
let loginUser = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let response = await fetch(
    "https://estudio-ghibli-2022.herokuapp.com/login",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: e.target.username.value,
        password: e.target.password.value,
      }),
    }
  );
  let data = await response.json();
  console.log("data: ", data);
};

let contextData = {
  loginUser: loginUser,
};
```

This is my login page:

```jsx
const Login = () => {
  const { loginUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <FormInner>
      <Title>Studio Ghibli Tracker</Title>
      <Subtitle>Login</Subtitle>
      <Container>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="username" placeholder="example@mail.com" />
        <img src={userLogo} alt="user logo" />
      </Container>
      <Container>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" placeholder="******" />
        <img src={key} alt="key logo" />
      </Container>

      <LoginBtn type="button" onClick={loginUser}>
        Login
      </LoginBtn>
    </FormInner>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `loginUser` function is attached to the `<LoginBtn>` *click* event. Assuming that component passes some kind of `Event` to the handler, it's probably an event triggered by a `<button>` (or similar) which is what is assigned to `e.target`. There won't be any `username` property.

What you should be doing here is have your `username` and `password` inputs be [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) with their value tied to state

```js
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

and

```html
<input
  value={username}
  placeholder="example@mail.com"
  onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
/>
<input
  type="password"
  value={password}
  placeholder="******"
  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Your `loginUser` context function should accept `username` and `password` strings instead of an event

```js
const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://estudio-ghibli-2022.herokuapp.com/login",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    }
  );

  // don't forget to check for errors
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw response;
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("loginUser data:", data);
  // now do something with data ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
};
```

and

```html
<LoginBtn
  type="button"
  onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); loginUser(username, password); }
>Login</LoginBtn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access the value of username and password fields from non existing properties in your `loginUser` function:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  username: e.target.username.value,
  password: e.target.password.value,
})
```

I'm assuming that the param "`e`" is a `React.MouseEvent` because you are assigning `loginUser` as the handler of `onClick` event of the `<LoginBtn>` component:

```
<LoginBtn type="button"
          onClick={loginUser}>
  Login
</LoginBtn>
```

So unless you have a custom implementation in that component that somehow extracts this data from the form, there's a good chance that `e.target` points to an element that is not relevant for you to get this information.

So you could use Phil's suggested approach in the other answer using controlled components for the inputs to fix the issue or you could also set your handler to an `onSubmit` event of the form containing this elements and extract the information using `FormData` like this:

```
let loginUser = async (e) => {
  ...
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const { username, password } = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

  let response = await fetch(..., {
    ...
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
  );
  ...
};
```

Assuming that `<FormInner>` has `onSubmit` event:

```
<FormInner onSubmit={loginUser}>
```